# How to use "org.eclipse.ui.internalTweaklets"

Tags: eclipse-plugin

No usage information of this extension point is found in Google
Although it is internal, I still want to know how to use it

Comment: There isn't really a way to describe this in general. A particular tweaklet is defined by some internal Eclipse class and each one behaves in a completely different way. There are only 3 defined in the core Eclipse.

Comment: Use it to do what?

Comment: I was studying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This extension point is a way for internal Eclipse code to define classes to make small changes (tweaks) to various operations.

The format of the extension point is:

```xml
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.internalTweaklets">
    <tweaklet
          definition="org.eclipse.ui.internal.tweaklets.TitlePathUpdater"
          id="org.eclipse.ui.cocoa.titlePathUpdaterTweaklet"
          implementation="org.eclipse.ui.internal.cocoa.CocoaTitlePathUpdater"
          name="Cocoa Title Path Updater">
   </tweaklet>
</extension>
```

On my Eclipse on macOS this the only use of this extension point.

`definition` is the name of an existing abstract class in Eclipse. Only classes which support tweaklets can be specified, this is **not** a general mechanism to change anything.

`implementation` is a class extending the abstract class that is being provided by the plug-in.

`id` and `name` don't appear to be used.

The particular extension point I have shown is only used on macOS and is used to set the call the `NSWindow.representedFile` API when the main window title is set.